# Can anyone guide me in installing a driver for Epson Stylus C59 in Mac Lion?

Tags: macos, mac, printing

I've got a new mac mini (the latest one mid-2011) and it has Lion in it. I have an old Epson Stylus C59 and would like to use it in this mac mini. However, the epson site has no installer for mac.

Has anyone come up with a workaround? Please share if you know. I know this printer is already old buy hey, it still works :)

UPDATE:
I found Gutenprint http://gimp-print.sourceforge.net/MacOSX.php for Epson and the closest is Epson Stylus C50. Does anyone know if this works for Epson Stylus C59?

Comment: You should first try your printer. Most likely Lion already has drivers installed. If not, it'll prompt you and download and install the proper drivers automatically. That's a Mac. Things just work. You no longer have to go hunting around for drivers.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the following

[OSX Supported Epson complete list](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3669#epson)

The closest I found that was support by OS X was Epson Stylus C60.

[Epson Stylus C60 Ink Jet Printer Download page](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/support/supDetail.jsp?BV_UseBVCookie=yes&oid=14416&prodoid=7512895&infoType=Downloads&platform=Macintosh)

Comment: It is quite possible that you could find success by utilizing the C60 driver.